# MySQL gives unknown column error in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL statement i am unable to run it:

```
SELECT fm . * , mp.first_name, mp.last_name, mp.image, mp.member_id
FROM featured_members AS fm
JOIN member_profiles AS mp WHERE fm.member_id = mp.member_id
AND fm.member_type_id =6
AND fm.site_id =1
```

when i run it it gives me `#1054 - Unknown column 'fm.site_id' in 'on clause'` error

is there a syntax problem because fm table does have that site_id column but i don't know why SQL is not fetching it??

My Tables Structure for  `featured_members` is like this:

```
1 sr_no     
2 member_id     
3 member_type_id 
4 site_id
```

and for `member_profiles` the structure is:

```
1 member_profile_id 
2 member_id     
3 first_name    
4 middle_name   
5 last_name     
6 gender
7 image
```

Comment: what do your tables look like ?

Comment: fm.site_id  do you have site_id column in featured_members table? check it...

Comment: I Updated it with table structure

Comment: And your positive you're connected to the right database? I for instance sometimes check develop database instead of production database or viceversa

Comment: The query shown in your question could not have produced the error shown in your question, irrespective of the tables.  In particular, the query does not have an `'on clause'`, so the error (at best) would have been `... in 'where clause'`.  Have you tried to simplify the query for the purposes of this question and, in so doing, materially changed it?  I suspect you may have been mixing implicit joins with explicit ones and got caught out by join precedence resulting the `fm` table not being available for the evaluation of the `site_id` criterion.

Comment: @DonSeba Totally i am testing in my phpmyadmin and inside the same database if i remove site_id check Query works like a charm but when i add that condition it start giving error i don't know why

Comment: @eggyal So can what could be the solution you think ??

Comment: what do you get from the following query : 

SELECT fm . *
FROM featured_members AS fm
WHERE fm.member_type_id =6
AND fm.site_id =1

Comment: As asked in my previous comment: "*Have you tried to simplify the query for the purposes of this question and, in so doing, materially changed it?*"  If so, you will need to provide the query that is *actually* causing the given error in order for anyone to be able to debug it.

Comment: @DonSeba Same error of site_id i don't know why even its there in the table

Comment: @eggyal yes i actually did it but thing is it was working fine untill i added site_id check because of requirements change i also have to add the site_id check as well but then i get this unknown column error

Comment: @PHPSeeker, well I cant see what you see, but I'm confident that you are doing something wrong. last thing you can do is to check if there are no leading/trailing whitespaces in the fieldname.

Comment: "*yes i actually did it*" - did **what**?  Simplified the query?  Then please provide the **actual** query that's causing this error.  Please also show output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE featured_members`.

Comment: @DonSeba OMG Shit i didn't notice that thing its working now there was a small space after site_id God seriously i was having too much headache thats the reason i wasn't able to think of that thing Thanks alot everyone You helped alot !!

Comment: @eggyal Thanks mate i figured out still thanks alot for giving your helping comments about Join conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong: 
With JOIN's it is mandatory to use the ON clause, unless otherwise it's a cross join.

```
SELECT fm . * , mp.first_name, mp.last_name, mp.image, mp.member_id
FROM   featured_members AS fm
JOIN   member_profiles  AS mp ON ( fm.member_id = mp.member_id )
WHERE fm.member_type_id =6
AND fm.site_id =1
```

Comment: so share the table columns with us

Comment: i did @DonSeba Please check it now

Comment: @DonSeba with `joins` you must use ON otherwise how do you join the tables? It's not just good practice!

Comment: @bonCodigo: In MySQL, `JOIN` without a criterion is a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @eggyal here it's not about `CROSS JOIN` which is the exception.. :)

Comment: @bonCodigo: My point was merely that, in MySQL at least, it is not mandatory to specify join criteria.

Comment: @eggyal Agree but the way it's stated above in the answer is rather ambiguous unless it was specifically said `In MySQL` and same goes to my comment as well.

Comment: @DonSeba You may say that in MYSQL `on` is mandatory with `join` unless otherwise it's a `cross join` =)

Answer (score 1):

test this:

```
SELECT fm.*, mp.first_name, mp.last_name, mp.image, mp.member_id
FROM featured_members AS fm
LEFT JOIN member_profiles AS mp ON fm.member_id = mp.member_id
WHERE fm.member_type_id =6 AND fm.site_id =1
```

Answer (score 1):

The "on" clause is missing in your query, and MySQL needs it. So the solution provided by Moddom is the right answer, to my mind.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html and also http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13551.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT fm . * , mp.first_name, mp.last_name, mp.image, mp.member_id
FROM featured_members AS fm, member_profiles AS mp
WHERE fm.member_id = mp.member_id
AND fm.member_type_id =6
AND fm.site_id =1
```

The JOIN clause in your statement is expecting a corresponding ON which is what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT fm . * , mp.first_name, mp.last_name, mp.image, mp.member_id <br>
FROM featured_members fm , member_profiles mp <br>
where fm.member_id = mp.member_id <br>
AND fm.member_type_id =6 <br>
AND fm.site_id =1
```